# Combining grouped radio button methods into one?

Tags: c#, wpf, radio-button, checked

I have four radio buttons in the same group. Depending on which one is checked, a variable will change like so:

```
    public void radiobutton1_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        angle_Offset = 0 - direction;
    }

    public void radiobutton2_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        angle_Offset = 90 - direction;
    }

    public void radiobutton3_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        angle_Offset = 180 - direction;
    }

    public void radiobutton4_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        angle_Offset = 270 - direction;
    }
```

I'm trying to find a way to reduce that code. I tried some if/else statements but it was just as long, and the variable didn't update when checking a different button. Any tips would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assign tags to your radio buttons and make an array of angles that correspond to these tags, you could use a single method to process them all.

Assign 0 to the tag of the first radio button, 1 to the tag of the second radio button, 2 to the tag of the third radio button, and 3 to the forth radio button. Now your event handler can be rewritten as follows:

```
public void radiobutton2_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    var rb = (RadioButton)sender;
    var tag = Convert.ToInt32(rb.Tag);
    angle_Offset = (90*tag) - direction;
}
```

Comment: I tried what you said, and I get an error here: "var tag = (int)rb.Tag;"
Specified cast is not valid.
I assigned the 4 radio buttons 0-3, and made their isChecked properties point to the same method. I like the idea though, definitely what I had in mind. I never used tags before.

Comment: @pfinferno Did you assign the tags programmatically, or through the designer? If you did it through the designer, try using `Convert` instead of a cast.

Comment: Through the designer. What you suggested worked. Changed it to Convert.ToInt32. Works great now. Thank you very much!